# PowerBI Service Dataset Deployment

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a scenario where I deploy Dataset using PowerBi service deployment pipelines. Dev is connected to the dev database, test and prod to the production database.

When I work in dev, the dataset has more columns due to the difference between dev & prod databases, so when I deploy to test/prod workspaces, the dataset fails to refresh, and I don't want to deploy SQL at the same time.

How to deal with this scenario in Power BI service deployment pipelines?

Comment: Will you be able to share the error that you are getting while refreshing? have you used direct query or import for datasets?

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue driving this behaviour is that your queries have picked up inadvertent references to the additional columns.  The most common steps where this happens are the generated **Change Type** steps.

To resolve this, I would work through the queries and add **Choose Columns** steps as early as possible, to restrict the data to just the common columns.  Ideally steps those would be inserted just after the **Source, Navigation** steps that are commonly generated for database sources.